# Is it able to trigger a `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event programmatically on android?

Tags: android, events

Here is some simple android code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // do something
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // do something
            // how to trigger a ACTION_DOWN event here?
            break;
}
```

I want to trigger a `ACTION_DOWN` event when I handle `ACTION_MOVE`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // do something
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // do something
            // how to trigger a ACTION_DOWN event here?
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
            onTouch(v,event);
            break;
             }
}
```